# Magento 2 : How to specify compatible versions of extension when publishing on Marketplace

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, marketplace

How can I specify Magento extension is only compatible with **Magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x** when submitting it to **Magento Marketplace**?

Comment: I think in marketpalce option available to select the version of extesnion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is dedicated field on extension submission "Magento Edition Version" , make sure your extension and composer file meet the requirements for each version of Magento 2 - require correct PHP versions etc. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

[image]